# How to select all characters to the right of a specific character in a string - PHP

Tags: php, string, substr, strpos, chars

I spent a long time trying to figure this out!  How do I select all the characters to the right of a specific character in a string when I don't know how many characters there will be?

Comment: the function [strstr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) does just that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do:

```
$str = 'some_long_string';
echo explode( '_', $str, 2)[1]; // long_string
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// find the position of the first occurrence of the char you're looking for
$pos = strpos($string, $char);

// cut the string from that point
$result = substr($string, $pos + 1);
```

Comment: Probably want to substr on `$pos+1` to get only right of that character.

Comment: And now for multibyte characters! UTF-8 for the win!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this would fit your needs, but :

```
$string = explode(',','I dont know how to, get this part of the text');
```

Wouldn't $string[1] always be the right side of the delimiter? Unless you have more than one of the same in the string... sorry if it's not what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes!  You are correct!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Strange I couldn't find it with my searches.  :)

Comment: This fails when you have more than one of the delimiter in the string. You need to specify the limit parameter [as I did in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16348360/862594).

Answer (score 1):

Use `strpos` to find the position of the specific character, and then use `substr` to grab all the characters after it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `strstr`

```
$data = 'Some#Ramdom#String';
$find = "#" ;
$string = substr(strstr($data,$find),strlen($find));
echo $string;
```

Output

```
Ramdom#String
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use substr with a negative starting integer

```
$startingCharacter = 'i';
$searchString = 'my test string';
$positionFromEnd = strlen($searchString)
    - strpos($searchString, $startingCharacter);
$result = substr($searchString, ($positionFromEnd)*-1);
```

or in a function:

```
function strRightFromChar($char, $string) {
    $positionFromEnd = strlen($string) - strpos($string, $char);
    $result = substr($string, ($positionFromEnd)*-1);
    return $result;
}
echo strRightFromChar('te', 'my test string');
```

(Note that you can search for a group of characters as well)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming I want to select all characters to the right of the first underscore in my string:

```
$stringLength = strlen($string_I_want_to_strip);
$limiterPos = strpos($string_I_want_to_strip, "_");
$reversePos = $limiterPos - $stringLength + 1;
$charsToTheRight = substr($string_I_want_to_strip, $reversePos, $limiterPos);
```

Comment: I put this into production already because it does exactly what I want... It selects all characters to the right of a delimiter.  The better method is "explode()" however.